# Package braids warning

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, braids

Anyone run into this warning?

```
Package braids Warning: This package was designed using PGF2.10; you are using 3.0.1a.
```

I made sure that I had `\usepackage{tikz}` before `\usepackage{braids}`. The actual code for the braid is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\braid[number of strands=4,
       style strands={5,6}{draw=none}] (braid) a_2 a_1 a_3 a_2 a_2 a_1 a_3 a_2;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: Isn't the warning somewhat self-explanatory? The `braids` package was developed with version 2.10 of `pgf` (which is the backend of TikZ), while you have got version 3 of `pgf`. There were quite a few changes between version 2 and 3 I believe.

Comment: I don't get that warning with my installation (but a get a different warning saying to use `\usetikzlibrary{braids}` instead of `\usepackage{braids}`), I'm guessing updating `braids` will make the warning go away.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I have the same warning, but when iI replace with `\usetikzlibrary{braids}` , I obtain an error message: `undefined command \braids`…

Comment: @Bernard Ah, yes. The library version defines a different syntax with `\pic`s, but the package version is still available. So for a new document, prefer the library, but for an old one with existing `\braid`s, the package can be used.

Comment: The warning was originally there because when I originally wrote it, PGF2.10 was _cutting edge_ and not everyone used it, so the warning was for those people.  Then when PGF 3 came along with its `\pic` syntax, I rewrote it to make use of that.  If using it from fresh, I *strongly* recommend using the newer version. Please look at the documentation to see the different syntax.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. When I used  `\usetikzlibrary{braids}` instead, I got the error  `Package tikz Error: I did not find the tikz library 'braids'. `

Comment: Yes, because you have an older version, from before the library existed.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I see. Would you mind telling me specifically what I should do to? Thank you. I'm very new to this. Sorry.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Right. That makes senses. So what package should I use, in order to have the braid drawing? Thank you.

Comment: If the one you have doesn’t work, then update it to the latest version I suppose. Edit: I know nothing of braids, or packages to draw them, really.

Comment: It sounds like your TeX distribution is quite old.  Best would be to update the whole thing - there are questions here about that - which will also update the braids package.